# vue 3 js vuetify component v-data-table not resolving table data object

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I'm new to vue and trying vuetify components for UI. I facing problem with v-data-table component of vuetify in localhost. Using vue 3 with vuetify 3 component v-data-table but no table was rendered in the browser throws no console error or eslint, [Browser devtool inspecting v-data-table element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5S3X.png)
Below is the npm serve of project runs successfully[node terminal npm serve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pw2NQ.png)

other components like v-navigation-drawer, v-app-bar are working fine.
Using vue cli for scaffolding the app vue 3 and vuetify 3.3.10
below added project package.json  main.js App.vue vuetify.js and datatable.vue component where table data are added

```
package.json
{
  "name": "multi_filter_data_table",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/font": "5.9.55",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "roboto-fontface": "*",
    "vue": "^3.3.4",
    "vuetify": "^3.3.10",
    "webfontloader": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "~1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "~2.5.8",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack-plugin-vuetify": "^2.0.0-alpha.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import { loadFonts } from './plugins/webfontloader'

loadFonts()

createApp(App)
  .use(vuetify)
  .mount('#app')
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <DataTable/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import DataTable from './components/DataTable.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',

  components: {
    DataTable,
  },

  data: () => ({
    //
  }),
}
</script>
```

vuetify.js

```
// Styles
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'

// Vuetify
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

export default createVuetify(
  // https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
)
```

datatable.vue

````
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="desserts"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  ></v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        headers: [
          {
            text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
            align: 'start',
            sortable: false,
            value: 'name',
          },
          { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
          { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
          { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
          { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
          { 
            text: 'Iron (%)',
            value: 'iron',
            sort: (a, b) => {
              a = a.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
              b = b.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
              return a-b;
            }
          },
        ],
        desserts: [
          {
            name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
            calories: 159,
            fat: 6.0,
            carbs: 24,
            protein: 4.0,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
            calories: 237,
            fat: 9.0,
            carbs: 37,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '1%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Eclair',
            calories: 262,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 23,
            protein: 6.0,
            iron: '7%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Cupcake',
            calories: 305,
            fat: 3.7,
            carbs: 67,
            protein: 4.3,
            iron: '8%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Gingerbread',
            calories: 356,
            fat: 16.0,
            carbs: 49,
            protein: 3.9,
            iron: '16%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Jelly bean',
            calories: 375,
            fat: 0.0,
            carbs: 94,
            protein: 0.0,
            iron: '0%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Lollipop',
            calories: 392,
            fat: 0.2,
            carbs: 98,
            protein: 0,
            iron: '2%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Honeycomb',
            calories: 408,
            fat: 3.2,
            carbs: 87,
            protein: 6.5,
            iron: '45%',
          },
          {
            name: 'Donut',
            calories: 452,
            fat: 25.0,
            carbs: 51,
            protein: 4.9,
            iron: '22%',
          },
          {
            name: 'KitKat',
            calories: 518,
            fat: 26.0,
            carbs: 65,
            protein: 7,
            iron: '6%',
          },
        ],
      }
    },
  }
</script>```

I have found to use v-data-table This feature requires v3.1.0 (Valkyrie) and vue 3 I have used this version


How can i implement the table for proper display of data in browser
````

Comment: VDataTable is not provided out-of-the-box by Vuetify 3, as it's still being developed and not considered a production ready component.  It's part of what's called "Vuetify Labs" and has separate installation instructions. See the [documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/#what-is-labs)

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in many example in web show implementation of v-data-table is particularly works fine with CDN link. but I using VUE-CLI where i face this issue. For you reference I found this in git hub https://github.com/jmauito/vue-multi-filter-data-table which uses data table and works fine without any issue. I found different type of import other which usually available in vue cli scaffolding, can you help me in this.

Comment: Those many examples you found are all using Vuetify 2.  Vuetify 3 is a complete rewrite of the Vuetify framework, all the components had to be rewritten by the developers, and VDataTable **specifically in Vuetify 3** is not production ready and has separate installation instructions. I've already given you the official Vuetify documentation link with the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specifically add Lab components (ex v-data-table) in your vuetify config.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/

Ex.

```js
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as labsComponents from 'vuetify/labs/components'

export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    ...components,
    ...labsComponents,
  },
})
```

Comment: Follow up... you no longer need to import it with the labs.